# Maximum speed of PIND read

Tags: avr

Ive got a square wave that I want to input into an avr. Im planning to configure PORTD to be inputs, then use PIND to read the state of the input. If its a one do something and vice versa. The freq is pretty quick 20khz. How can I ensure the read statement can work as quick as the input changes ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: 20kHz is actually pretty slow from a micro controller perspective. Even when using a AVR that is probably "only" clocked in the 8-16MHz area. Thats still a factor of 400. So as long as you don't have any other time consuming blocking code, you could easily poll the port input without thinking much about performance/speed. However, a more elegant solution would be to use an edge triggered interrupt.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like straightforward PIND polling should do the job. Ill have something like if(PIND etc).  One question, how often does the microcontroller execute that line that? If it gets a logic one say, how long till it re runs the if statement again, are we talking less then uS?

Comment: Well, you never told what your CPU clock is. But that one byte comparison in the if-statement should execute in a few instructions. You could take a look at the generated assembler output. With 8MHz the controller can perform 8 instructions per microsecond. So I would tend to say less than 1us.

Comment: Im using an atmega 328p, The clock freq is 20mhz. If its 8 per second at 8mhz that must mean its 20 per second at 20mhz ? the time period for my data is 50uS. So that leaves ample time to poll for the next data bit then. I was slightly concerned that the polling might not check quick enough, does this seem ok to you ?.

Comment: Not all the AVR instructions have a duration of 1 cycle, but a lot of AVR instructions have, see the data sheet (IE: some jumps have different timing). To get a "perfect' wave you should use an edge triggered interrupt (as Rev1.0 suggested), but I think the 328p at 20 MHz should not have issues to manage a 20kHz clock!

Comment: You should (as a general advice) try to include information about what exactly you want to achieve in your question. So far we only know that you want to "observe" some 20kHz input square. But we don't know why, what the signal represents, what the duty cycle is, if it changes etc. and what actions you want to perform as a consequence.

Comment: My signal is coming out of a phototransistor. It is a a square wave of data packets. each data packet is 63 bits long, mixture of ones and zeros. The time period for each bit is 50uS. I want to read this into the microcontroller, capture each 63 bits and then output the data to a text file. The data represents signals down a cable. I think the duty cycle would be 100% because the bit remains high or low for 100% of the 50uS.

Comment: After each 63 bits the square wave stays low for a few uS then back up to the next data packet.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing PIND register, using IN operator requires 1 system clock. Therefore you can do up to several millions PIND pulling operations in each second.

The delay between input pin value changed and your application reacts to it depends on how your application is written.

To reach minimum delay, when your application is idling  you can use cycles like that:

```
loop:
   sbis PIND, 0
   rjmp loop
// exits when input level on PD0 become high.
```

if your application doing some actions, you can use a pin change interrupt (depending on what device you are using).
Interrupts usually requires much more system clocks: 4 clocks to enter interrupt, and usually 4-10 to save registers and SREG

Note that delay between changed level applied to input pin, and this value become visible in PINx register is always in range 0.5 to 1.5 of systems clocks.

If you are not interested to perform a reaction as fast as pin level changed, you can just lazy pulling it value. When you CPU running at 8MHz, 20kz it is 200 CPU cycles between level changes.

Comment: The last point you make is true for me. As soon as the pin level changes I want to capture that value and store it in a string (for use later on). As you suggested if you can do a million reads on PIND in a second I dont think I should have a problem. Do you agree ?